# Why is the WMI win32_Process commandline property is giving null for only some processes of non-admin users?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vbscript, wmi

I have created a non-admin user, and trying to get details of Win32_Process but i'm either not getting any value or incorrect value for commandLine argument. I followed below steps to create the non-admin user and to give permissions to the non-admin user:

1.Non-admin User creation
2.Setting up the WMI configuration
3.Setting up the DCOM Access for non-admin user on the stand-alone Windows server

To Verify whether the issue is in our code or not I created a below .vbs script -
' VBScript to query Win32_Process

```
    ' Create the WMI service object
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        
    ' Query Win32_Process
    Set colProcess= objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess In colProcess
        WScript.Echo "Process Name: " & objProcess.Name & ",Command line: " & objProcess.commandline
    Next
```

As I executed this script from Administrator user it is giving proper o/p as-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZDo.png)
But for the non-admin user I'm not getting value of commandLine as below -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDKf1.png)

What steps should I take to get the correct value of commandLine?

Comment: Please don't re-post a question if it is closed, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78178532/edit) the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78178532/692942) and fix the issues raised by the closure notice to have it re-opened when/if resolved. You also seem to have completely ignored the comments the community has left and started a new question instead. Please if you haven't already take the [tour] and read [ask] before posting.